# How to get Spotify iOS currently playing track

Tags: swift, spotify

I'm using `SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance().metadata.currentTrack?.uri` to get the currently playing track, but sometimes it returns the next song on the playlist, instead of what is playing right now.

**Edit:** I think it may have to do with the playlist it is playing from, since whenever I skip a track, it deletes from the playlist. Is there a way to play from the top song in the playlist every time a skip occurs?

**Or even better:** Is there a way to refresh a playlist?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a delegate method and locally keep track of what track is playing:

```
func audioStreaming(_ audioStreaming: SPTAudioStreamingController!, didStartPlayingTrack trackUri: String!) {
  self.currentURI = trackURI
}
```

Whenever a track starts playing, the delegate method will fire and you can locally store the current URI. Just make sure to also utilize the other delegate methods like `didStopPlayingTrack` in order to ensure you have all the correct information.